# Variable Length Argument List (using Get)

Tags: java, get, variable-length

I cannot seem to understand the concept of variable length argument lists. When I do a bit of research, it makes sense, but I can't figure out this question to save my life.

What is the result of the following call?

```
get(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7); // The Call

public int get(int ... a) {
    return a[2];
}
```

My answer was "2" which is the only thing that makes sense to me. The other options were 1, 3, or 4. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's just like a regular array. It returns the value at the index `2`, which would be `3`. Remember that arrays are zero-based.

Comment: Why don't you test it? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Arrays are zero based. Which is to say the first item is at position 0, the second at position 1. So the item at position 2 in your case is the integer   3

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone! I find programming to be akin to math; I'm always forgetting at least one simple detail/rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are zero based. Which is to say the first item is at position 0, the second at position 1. So the item at position 2 in your case is the integer 3.